# Subject Alternative Name is not copied to signed certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, self-signed, ca

I use self-signed CA cert to sign other certificates. For some certs I need to specify subject alternative names. I can specify them during request generation (`openssl req ...`) and I see them in .csr file. Then I sign it with CA cert using

```
openssl x509 -req -extensions x509v3_config -days 365 -in ${name}.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out ${name}.crt
```

and next sections in openssl.cnf file:

```
[ x509 ]
x509_extensions = x509v3_config

[ x509v3_config ]
copy_extensions = copy
```

but I see no SAN in .crt file.

I know about [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297139/how-do-you-sign-certificate-signing-request-with-your-certification-authority) with `openssl ca ...` command but I have no valid `[ca]` section and I don't want to copy/paste it without deep understanding what it does. So I hope that exists another solution with `openssl x509 ...` command.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `copy_extensions` directive is only understood by the `openssl ca` command.  There is no way to copy extensions from a CSR to the certificate with the `openssl x509` command.

Instead, you should specify the *exact* extensions you want as part of the `openssl x509` command, using the same directives you used for `openssl req`.

Comment: This is no longer true since OpenSSL v3. Please se my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60656045/797243

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, I can't comment (yet).

In addition to @frasertweedale :

I generated my server-certificate with a config file

```
openssl req -new -out certificate.csr -key certificate_private_key.pem -sha256 -days 1825 -config certificate.conf
```

I then did

> Instead, you should specify the exact extensions you want as part of the OpenSSL x509 command, using the same directives you used for OpenSSL req.

with the following command (I used the same .conf-file again):

```
openssl x509 -req -in certificate.csr -CA ca-root-public-certificate.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out certificate_public.pem -sha256 -days 1825 -extfile certificate.conf -extensions v3_req
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a good documentation here : [Certificates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/certificates/)

You will need to compose an openssl conf file while creating a x509 cert request like this:

create CSR

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -config csr.conf
```

sign CERT

```
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 10000 -extensions v3_ext -extfile csr.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently (2023), the accepted answer is no longer true, as it is indeed possible to use `copy_extensions` with openssl's `x509` command since OpenSSL v3.

Docs: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-x509.html

So, with OpenSSL version 3 upwards, you can now copy the extensions you previously defined in your signing request by doing something like this:

```
openssl x509 -req \
   -copy_extensions copyall \
   -days 365 \
   -in my.csr \
   -signkey ca.key \
   -out my.crt
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin! This handy flag allows you to avoid using a separate config file.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the copy_extensions flag to resolve this issue.
so the right way to use it as a flag like given below:

```
-copy_extensions=copyall
```

Note that value can be different according to the requirement.